How to upload crashlytics native symbol in Android?
I am applying firebase crashlytics to the project.
The projects we are developing include apps and SDKs.
The SDK contains the engine.so file.
In order to avoid striping, we implemented it as follows.
packagingOptions {
                doNotStrip "*/arm64-v8a/*.so"
                doNotStrip "*/armeabi-v7a/*.so"

                jniLibs {
                    useLegacyPackaging = true
                }
            }

After building aar for sdk application to the app, when I checked the engine.so file inside,
$ FILE engine.so
engine.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, with debug_info, not stripped

I have confirmed that it contains debug_info.
After applying SDK to the app, it was implemented as below to apply crashlytics.
build.gradle (project)
plugins {
    //...
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '3.0.2' apply false
}

build.gradle (app)
plugins {
    //...

    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android {
   buildTypes {
        debug {
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled true
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
            }
        }
}

tasks.configureEach { task -> if (task.name.startsWith('assemble') && task.name.endsWith("Debug")) task.finalizedBy "uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFile" + task.name.substring('assemble'.length()) }

dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk'
}

The application of Crashlytics was successful.
In the event of a crash, it could be seen in the crashlytics of the Firebase console.
However, the collision on engine.so is undetected and shows the wrong stacktrace.
crashlytics of the firebase console
null pointer dereference: SIGSEGV  0x0000000000000000
#00 pc 0x6fa91b5b88
#01 pc 0x6fa91b5b6c
#02 pc 0x218964 libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#03 pc 0x285ff0 libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#04 pc 0x3dce0c libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#05 pc 0x3ea4c8 libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#06 pc 0xa16ffc libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#07 pc 0x3e5064 libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#08 pc 0x760518 libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#09 pc 0xa16ffc libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#10 pc 0x77ebfc libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#11 pc 0x203814 libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#12 pc 0xa16ffc libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#13 pc 0x2000fc libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#14 pc 0xa16ffc libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#15 pc 0x3dce0c libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#16 pc 0x3e4584 libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#17 pc 0xa16ffc libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#18 pc 0x800ba4 libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#19 pc 0x3e5040 libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#20 pc 0x760518 libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#21 pc 0xa16ffc libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#22 pc 0x76d498 libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#23 pc 0xa16ffc libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#24 pc 0x77f2a0 libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#25 pc 0x77ebfc libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#26 pc 0x203814 libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#27 pc 0xa16ffc libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#28 pc 0x2000fc libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#29 pc 0xa16ffc libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#30 pc 0x3dce0c libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#31 pc 0x2000fc libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#32 pc 0x3e4584 libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#33 pc 0xa16ffc libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)
#34 pc 0x3e5040 libart.so (BuildId: 4752fd49b3f5a76fd788c235cf2fb143)

Stacktrace not found for engine.so .
I've also tried symbol upload using Firebase cli.
app/build/intermidiates/merged_native_libs/appDebug/out/lib
Compress a folder
And,
firebase crashlytics:symbols:upload --app="appId" path\lib.zip

However, I couldn't find a Crash stack trace for engine.so in Crashlytics.
How to uplaod ndk symbol for Crashlytics?
nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
and ./gradlew :app:assembleAppDebug uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileAppDebug
and Firebase CLI
firebase crashlytics:symbols:upload --app="appId" path/lib.zip
